# How do you specify a tab in .screenrc?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

According to [this website](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/screen-power-tips-screenrc/), you can change to command key sequence used by the Unix "screen" utility like this:

```
escape ^Bb # Instead of Control-a, make the 
           # escape/command character be 
           # Control-b
```

How would you make it Control-Tab, I wonder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never tried it, but you may have a go with this [link](http://www.staldal.nu/tech/2009/01/10/how-to-use-ctrl-tab-in-gnu-screen/)

Comment: I was about to say, "terminal treats Ctrl-Tab just like Tab, this isn't possible"... but if you can change the terminal's behavoir, that's great!

Comment: Yes, well. He didn't say anything about what terminal he's using.